# Handle an event from a UserControl inside a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, user-controls, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am writing a Windows 10 Universal App, in which I have a ListView with its DataTemplate being a UserControl. Inside that UserControl there's a button whose click event I want to handle on my MainPage.

It's basically a list of contacts, and the button is supposed to remove a contact from the list when clicked, and have no idea how can I handle the UserControl's button click.

This is the XAML for the UserControl:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="DataBinding_Test1.ContactControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:DataBinding_Test1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="50">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Name="ContactIconTextBlock"
               Style="{StaticResource IconStyle}"
               Text="{x:Bind myContact.ContactIcon}"/>
    <TextBlock Name="ContactNameTextBlock"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
               Text="{x:Bind myContact.ContactName}"
               RelativePanel.RightOf="ContactIconTextBlock"/>
    <Button Name="RemoveContactButton"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Content="X"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Click="RemoveContactButton_OnClick"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Which is inside this ListView:

```
<ListView
        Name="ContactsListView"
        Grid.Column="1"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ContactList}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactListDataTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event handler in the code behind of the user control and call it in the click event of the button.

code behind:

```
public event EventHandler OnRemoveContact;

private void RemoveContactButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //... your existing code here
    OnRemoveContact?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

Now, you can use the event in your datatemplate into the code behind of your MainPage

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't why I didn't think about it before.